# Why do I get the information of "suspended (tty input)" when I run my script in the background

Tags: linux, shell, background-process, jobs

I've written a tcsh script to clear garbage data in a cluster, the code is :

```
set hosts = $1
set clear_path = $2
foreach i ($hosts)
    rsh $i rm -rvf $clear_path
end
```

When I run this script in the background like this :

```
disk_clean.sh hosts_all /u0/data/tmp > log &
```

The job will get stuck and show the information like this:

```
[1] + Suspended (tty input)
```

If I run this in foreground, it can finish normally. 
Why does this happen? How can I run this script in the background and redirect the output into a log file?

Comment: Rsh reads from standard input (the terminal in your case) and passes the data to the remote system. Unix and Linux systems stop a process when it's in the background and tries to read from the terminal. Give rsh the `-n` option to tell it not to read anything from standard input.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Access-to-the-Terminal.html#Access-to-the-Terminal

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! It seems that I didn't read the manpage of rsh carefully.