# nodemon run in background stops on terminal input

Tags: jobs, nodemon

I want to use `nodemon`, but still have the use of my terminal, so I ran

```
$ nodemon &> site.log &
```

But as soon as I type a single character at the prompt, nodemon stops with this message.

```
[1]  + 45260 suspended (tty input)  nodemon &> site.log
```

What's going on? How can I make this stop happening?

I'm running `zsh` on MacOS.

**EDIT:**
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361200/why-do-i-get-the-information-of-suspended-tty-input-when-i-run-my-script-in) answer which explains it perfectly - apparently `nodemon` tries to read from `stdin`, and unix systems will stop processes that try to read from `stdin` while in the background. So my question now becomes:

How do I get `nodemon` to stop reading from `stdin`? And, more generally, is there a way to get an arbitrary process to stop reading from `stdin`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I have to redirect `/dev/null` to the input.

```
$ nodemon < /dev/null &> site.log &
```